# create JSON file with objective-c

Tags: objective-c, json

I'm trying to write an application in which users can fill some text field and send the content to a server.

I have to do it using JSON and if it is possible without external framework.

How can I write a JSON file with objective-c?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`NSJSONSerialization` class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this. The `dataWithJSONObject:options:error:` method takes an `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` object and returns an `NSData` object that contains the object serialized to a valid JSON string. You can write this data to a file using the `writeToFile:atomically:` message.